# java indexOf ignores the first occurence

Tags: java, if-statement, indexof

Here is my code. And it looks so repetitive. Is there a way to make it look cleaner? Thanks. And my code is supposed to do something like this;
Enter text:
IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
 You entered: IDK if I'll go. It's my BFF's birthday.
BFF: best friend forever
IDK: I don't know

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextMsgDecoder {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      /* Type your code here. */
      String a = "BFF";
      String b = "IDK";      
      String c = "JK";
      String d = "TMI";
      String e = "TTYL";
      Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter text:");
      String f = scr.nextLine();
      System.out.println("You entered: "+ f);

      if(f.indexOf(a)>=0)
      System.out.println("BFF: best friend forever");
      if(f.indexOf(b)>=0)
      System.out.println("IDK: I don't know");
      if(f.indexOf(c)>=0)
      System.out.println("JK: just kidding");
      if(f.indexOf(d)>=0)
      System.out.println("TMI: too much information");
      if(f.indexOf(e)>=0)
      System.out.println("TTYL: talk to you later");



      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Change all the `indexOf(...) > ...` to `indexOf(...) >= ...`

Comment: You need to check `>= 0` or `> -1`

Comment: You should consider reading the documentation. What does `indexOf` return for the first character in a string? How are string characters counted? Think about why your code might be doing this, then take a closer look at your `if` statements.

Comment: Thanks guys. Now I noticed a different question and editted it.

Comment: You may want to look up Maps as well.

Comment: @EJoshuaS ok I'm going to editted back. Before I did that because no one bothered to answer my question and now there is an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to repeat what was said in the comments (since comments may be cleaned up),

```
if(f.indexOf(e)>0)
```

should actually be

```
if(f.indexOf(e)>=0)
```

Or, even better, just use `string.contains`.

A third choice is to create a hash table. I'm not sitting in front of an IDE and I'm writing this on a phone, but here's a rough idea (uses closer to C# syntax than "straight" Java):

```
// A C# Dictionary is a hash table
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("BFF", "Best Friend Forever");
// Add the rest of the abbreviations

// Loop over every key (abbreviation) in the hash table
foreach (string abbreviation in dict.Keys) {
    // If the string contains the abbreviation
    if (f.contains(abbreviation)) {

         Console.WriteLine(abbreviation + ": " + dict[key]);
    }
}
```

That's a lot easier to read/more concise if you add more abbreviations later.